# why data that is explicitly initialized to zero is generated into .data section?

Tags: c, ram

Data that is explicitly initialized to a non-zero value is generated into the .data section and data that is explicitly initialized to zero or left uninitialized is generated into the .bss section. Everything is right but I find that my data that is explicitly initialized to zero is generated into .data section. The compiler is Cosmic s12z.

For example, according to map file, .data has 17 bytes and .bss has 18 bytes. However, there are 13 bytes of data that is explicitly initialized to zero which generated into .data section. (So .data should has 4 bytes and .bss should has 31 bytes). And according to CXS12Z User Guide, there are two types of static data initializations:

1. data that is explicitly initialized to a non-zero value:
   `char var1 = 25;`
   which is generated into the .data section and
2. data that is explicitly initialized to zero or left uninitialized:
   `char var2;`
   which is generated into the .bss section.

But when I have some static or global data like follows:
`char var3 = 0;`
`char var4 = NONE; //NONE equals zero`
They are generated into .data section.

What can I do to get these data generated into .bss section?

Comment: I think BSS is only used for variables that use the default zero initialization. If you have an explicit initializer, it's put in DATA even if it happens to be zero.

Comment: There's no particular reason the compiler couldn't detect when the initializer is 0 and put the object in .bss in this case.  It may be that the authors of this particular compiler simply never bothered to implement that.  Or else it's a feature, to let you decide which you want by the choice of specifying an initializer or not.

Comment: Has your compiler an extension that allows the placement of objects in certain sections? I mean, like the `section` attribute of GCC. -- Did you ask the vendor? What did they say?

Comment: Redefining Sections feature is available, It is possible to redirect components to any user defined section by using the following pragma definition: #pragma section <attribute> <qualified_name>. But I hope I can just get data(initialized to zero) generated into .bss section without any other code in source file.